# Advice on how to work with this SQL CODE in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Your boss wants to just look at data from the last quarter of each year.  All years are to be selected.  Perform the following query but only select data in the last 3 months of each year here is the code I have so far but I'm having a hard time  selecting the last 3 month of each year:

```
SELECT Extract(YEAR from orderdate) as year,
   Extract(MONTH from orderdate) as month,
   COUNT(*) as numorders, COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) as numcust,
   SUM(totalprice) as totspend,
   SUM(totalprice)*1.0/COUNT(*) as avgordersize,
   SUM(totalprice)*1.0/COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) as avgcustorder

FROM dw.orders o
GROUP BY Extract(YEAR from orderdate),
     Extract(MONTH from orderdate)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Try adding a `WHERE` clause.  Also, please try to make homework less obvious.

Comment: It's just that it feels so wrong when it's homework.

Comment: @JNevill this isn't homework these are problem in a book that im trying to work on to become better at this

Comment: That makes me feel better!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce the number of rows returned, which implies that you need a `WHERE` clause. You also need to either translate the date into a value that represents its quarter or derive the 4th quarter of the year from the date. I'd recommend the former:

```
where to_char(orderdate,'Q') = '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside @Allen's answer You could also use something like `WHERE Extract(MONTH from orderdate) IN (10,11,12)` just to keep the syntax/logic similar to your existing stuff.